# Is it allowed to omit apostrophes after `s`?

Tags: difference, possessives, plural-forms, apostrophe

In [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30133/what-is-the-difference-between-s-and-s) meaning of the `s'` explained, but what if I'll say `my childrens toys` (several kids), i.e. with no ' after s ?

Comment: You need the possessive apostrophe. Omitting it is an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "correct" punctuation is "my children's toys"  (=the toys of my children)

> The toys of my child  -> my child's toys
> The toys of my children > my children's toys
> The toys of my son -> my son's toys
> The toys of my sons -> my sons' toys

The last two are pronounced the same.  Note that apostrophes are frequently used incorrectly by native speakers, so we are likely to be more forgiving of people who write childrens'

Comment: Yes. My children's toys, the crowd's voices, the people's vote.

Comment: Getting it wrong is quite common, as you say - though it would be a mistake for learners (or anyone else) to think they can or should ignore or disregard the rules: getting it right will always make a better impression on those who do know what's correct.